# jquery opposite of $(this)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to perform the reverse action of `$(this)`?

So instead of gettin the `this` element, it gets everything matching `.sb-popular-thumb a` but excluding `$(this)`?

See code below of example. I have marked `$(this)` with `$(reverse)` so you can see what I am trying to achieve.

```
$('.sb-popular-thumb a').hover(
  function () {

    $('.sb-popular').stop().animate({
        height : '168px'                    
    }, 200);

    $(this).siblings('.sb-popular-thumb-title').show();

    $(reverse).siblings('.sb-popular-thumb-overlay').stop().fadeIn(200);

  },
  function () {

    $('.sb-popular').stop().animate({
        height : '140px'                    
    }, 200);

    $(this).siblings('.sb-popular-thumb-title').hide();

    $(reverse).siblings('.sb-popular-thumb-overlay').stop().fadeOut(200);

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will imitate your 'reverse'

```
$('.sb-popular-thumb a').not($(this));
```

Answer (score 8):

just use :

```
$('.sb-popular-thumb a').not(this)
                        .siblings('.sb-popular-thumb-overlay')
                        .stop()
                        .fadeIn(200);
```

It will get all the `<a>` elements within that class except `this`.

`siblings()` will do almost the same, but will only get sibling elements (duh) ?

Answer (score 2):

`.not()` excludes whatever you specify from your search.

So `.not(this)` excludes this.

Comment: I did not know of .not - I will be using this alot more from now. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to tick one of the other blokes' answers as the one you accept :)